# Freeshipping not working correctly

Tags: magento2.3, free-shipping

Good morning,
We are unable to set the Freeshipping rule correctly.
We have a shipment for € 8.90 until reaching € 30, after which Free shipping should start.
Unfortunately magento continues to reason by taking as a reference "price - VAT" price as a consequence the rule does not trigger correctly, should use "cost + VAT" to trigger the rule but this does not happen, can someone help? thank you
Magento 2 latest release.
Thank you